# Need to understand iptables command

Tags: iptables

Can someone please help me to understand the meaning/operation of the following 2 commands?

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Did you read the manpage? Which part of it is unclear to you?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the man page. It is complex for beginner like me. I just want to know, what is the work performed by the above 2 commands?

Comment: It is very difficult to explain those two isolated commands to someone not knowing the basics of Linux networking. May I suggest you start by following an introductory networking course?

Comment: Even if you understand what these commands do, the understanding does not have much value unless you understand other concepts related to networking / firewalling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know, what is the work performed by the above 2 commands?

Well...

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

Adds a rule into OS firewall rules list that allows TCP protocol packets to out from computer programs to any IP address via any network interface.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT
```

Adds a rule into OS firewall rules list that allows TCP protocol packets to reach computer programs from any IP address via any network interface.

For start you may read this
https://www.booleanworld.com/depth-guide-iptables-linux-firewall/

Comment: Thank gapsf. just to clarify, the above 2 commands will disable all other rules?

Comment: No. But packets matched these rules are finally accepted and not checked against next rules further. Packets that did not match will be checked against other rules in list in sequental order until accepted or droped/rejected by some matched rule.

Comment: Okay, this will allow all incoming TCP packets, even from the blocked IPs ?

Comment: Thats depends of what you mean "blocked". Rules a evaluated one by one in their order in chain. Your rules inserted at very begging of the chain, so they checked first. So all tcp is allowed. Other non matched (non tcp) packets will be checked against rest of rules. Main idea here is rules are checked **sequentally** starting from the first in chain so total result is **highly depends** on 1. order of rules 2. what rules check/match and what it do with packet. You cannot judge without knowing other rules in chains and their order.

Comment: So in this concrete situation **any rules that match tcp** and goes **after** this one has no effect since previous is already match **and** accept So its final or terminating for tcp. If you insert/add block rule **before** this one it  will block (if match against packet) You can try and play with icmp proto and ping command.

Comment: Understood, is there any command to check the rules sequence?

Comment: iptables -nvL print rules from filter tables.

Answer (score 0):

See answer below.

These rules insert ( -I ) the ACCEPT targets for TCP at the beginning of the OUTPUT and INPUT chains, meaning that any TCP traffic will be allowed

Comment: In case you are interested this answer was generated with a tool called ConfigExpress